# In which version of Java were anonymous classes introduced?

Tags: java, anonymous-class

The purpose of anonymous classes is clear and understandable. But I'm unable to find the minimum version of Java which supports anonymous classes. Can anyone tell me the exact Java version which supports it?

Comment: I think Java 1, but i am not 100% sure

Comment: @Jens I can't find a mention in [the Java 1 spec](http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-1.0/15.doc.html).

Comment: The earliest mention I found, is in JLS 1.3

Comment: @KonstantinYovkov where do you find old language specs? I can only find 1 easily; then 6,7,8 on Oracle's website.

Comment: Inner classes were added in Java 1.1 (see [Java version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history)), I guess anonymous classes were added around the same time.

Comment: @AndyTurner, here I found [1.2](https://books.google.bg/books?id=Ww1B9O_yVGsC&pg=PR2&lpg=PR2&dq=java+language+specification+version+1.2&source=bl&ots=Sf4LdgRaoI&sig=WnLez614rlc9zYhDuoeQ17I3bCg&hl=bg&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAp_qwlpPOAhXoLcAKHYo7BBAQ6AEIYDAI#v=onepage&q=java%20language%20specification%20version%201.2&f=false), and here I found [1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/j3TOC.html)

Comment: @Konstantin thanks.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.

Comment: https://books.google.ca/books?id=Ww1B9O_yVGsC&q=anonymous%20class confirms that they were part of 1.2 (under Inner Classes)

Comment: I see they were part of 1.1. Please check https://www.cs.cornell.edu/andru/javaspec/1.1Update.html

Answer (score 7):

Java 1.1

Source: https://www.cs.cornell.edu/andru/javaspec/1.1Update.html

Details: Added along with inner classes. Anonymous classes are a type of Inner Class (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_class). Inner classes were introduced in Java 1.1 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history).